# Android app crashes unexpectedly

Tags: java, android

I am new to Android developement and had recently started on a project to get `WiFi SSID`, `BSSID` and `MAC` address. However, the app crashed unexpectedly immediately after opening it.

The error log in Android Studio says that:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.android.wifi, PID: 3875

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.android.wifi/com.example.android.wifi}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.Window.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
at
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2993)
at
android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3248)
at ...
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.Window.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
at
android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:2277)
at
com.example.android.wifi.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:16)
at ...
```

My `java` file can be found at [http://www.yikjin.ga/MainActivity.java](http://www.yikjin.ga/MainActivity.java.html)

There were no syntax errors recorded by Android Studio.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: where is your code???

Comment: Whoops sorry fixed the link

Comment: it seems you are referring xml object with wrong name ..check it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your error is seems you are trying to get the `View` inside the constructor of your class or you are calling `findViewById()` outside.

```
com.example.android.wifi.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:16)
```

Move those code to `onCreate()` method after calling `setContentView()`

**Update:**

Change

```
TextView viewWifiSSID = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.network);
TextView viewWifiBSSID = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.bssid);
TextView viewWifiMAC = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mac);
```

to

```
TextView viewWifiSSID;
TextView viewWifiBSSID;
TextView viewWifiMAC;
```

and add the following to `onCreate()` after `setContentView()`

```
viewWifiSSID = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.network);
viewWifiBSSID = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.bssid);
viewWifiMAC = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mac);
```

Comment: @MD: `<init>` represents the class constructor which means error was there and then `android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:2277)` shows that `findViewById` was called.

Comment: @MD: Unless you can point out the error without the code. Although I understand what you are saying.

Comment: I told you this becoz OP doesn't make this mistake again to asked question without having posted code. Actually by answering those questions we people encourage the OP to make such a mistakes again an again. Nothing else. +1 up. I will delete my answer and it's my today last vote.

Comment: @MD: I understand your point, didn't thought that way. Really appreciate your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

you are referring object before activity is created ... `onCreate()` is called when your activity is created so refer object inside `onCreate()`...

```
TextView viewWifiSSID, viewWifiBSSID, viewWifiMAC;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

  viewWifiSSID = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.network);
  viewWifiBSSID = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.bssid);
  viewWifiMAC = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mac);

  getWifi();
}
```

Comment: I thought this will cause the variables to localise?